# Fastest place to retrieve images in android

Tags: android, android-image, android-file

I'm developing a small social networking app that makes use of something like profile pictures. Images are stored on a server and I have scripts set up that will send the image for each user to the app, which then displays it in an image view for each user, and then saves the image to external storage. The way I have it implemented now is that anytime the app needs the image after it downloads it from the server, the app will get the image from external storage unless a user has uploaded a new image (I thought this would be faster than redownloading it from the server every time). However, it seems to be taking longer to get the file from external storage than it does to get it from my server (and the server is pretty slow, running on wifi from 3 floors away...budget constrains :) ).

My question is what is the fastest way to get these images if the user hasn't uploaded a new one. Should I just downlaod it from the server everytime (I'm assuming not) or is there a better place in the filesystem to store the images that makes for faster retrieval?

Comment: How are you storing the images?

Comment: I get an InputStream using a URLHttpConnection to the Image on the server, then I create a new file on android like this "new File(callingComponent.getExternalFilesDir("DIRECTORY PICTURES"), username + ".jpg");", then I get a byte[] from the InputStream and write it to the file using an OutputStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading images from the SD card should be very fast. Some strategies:

1. **Do it only once** - Load the images into memory asynchronously when your activity or application starts. You don't want to be hitting the SD card every time your view updates.
2. **Make them small** - If you're having performance problems displaying thumbnails in a list, try saving your thumbnails as smaller images using [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to put less pressure on the decoder.
3. **Use internal memory** - I *think* that internal memory is faster, but it tends to be in short supply. You could certainly store some number of thumbnails in your [cache directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) to help speed up step 1.
4. **Responsiveness over performance** - The golden rule is to remember that absolute performance does not always correlate with responsiveness. Even if the images take a long time to load, choosing cleverly *when* to load the images can have a great impact on the user's perception of speed.

Comment: Ok so I realized that the problem was when I tried to load the images from the SD card, BitmapFactory.decodeStream was returning null because apparently there's a bug when using InputStream with BitmapFactory.decodeStream. I fixed that and now on average it takes 14 seconds to download 10 images from the server, save, and display them, and when it reads from the SD card it takes 8 seconds everytime no matter what I set inSampleSize to, or if I compress the file to a quality of 10. Is this the best I could hope for from SD card? I'm just trying to get the most efficient times that I can for now

Comment: Did you try caching thumbnails in your cache directory? How many images is it taking 8 seconds to load?

Comment: Ah I knew I forgot to try something :) I'll try that tomorrow because I already shut Eclipse down. It took 8 seconds to load 10 images off the SD card.

Comment: By the way, you should be using inSampleSize before you save the images to the SD card so that the (thumbnail) images you save are smaller.

Comment: I set inSampleSize to both 2 and 4 (two different tests, not at the same time) and did a BitmapFactory.decodeStream sending it the BitmapFactory.Options parameter that I made. I then saved that Bitmap to the SD card

Comment: I used the cache for as many of the pictures as I could put when I upped the amount of pictures to 50 (which is probably an average of how many pictures there would need to be when I make the app live) and the difference between cache and SD card wasn't really that noticeable. I guess the best way to do this would be to strategically and asynchronously do all these operations, so you get the answer